# adding an alias to rspec for easier invocation of pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm looking to add some alias to easier invoke the binding.pry call to my tests. following along in the book "Effective Testing in RSpec 3" it states to add the following to my rspec config.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.alias_example_group_to :pdescribe, pry: true

  config.alias_example_to :pit, pry: true

  config.after(:example, pry: true) do |ex|
    require 'pry'
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

yet, when I try to add the #pit or #pdescribe
it invokes binding.pry in the config.after(:example) protion.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am not use, I used snippet you provided and I got pry working, yes it started on the portion of the stack inside the `after` block but the variables I defined using `let` were available for inspection, `subject` however would result in error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What you describe is the expected behavior. What was your expectation when adding this config?